# htaccess 301 redirect not working properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have rewrite URL via htaccess now I want to redirect that URL to another URL.

Below is my rewrite rule, which I am using for short URL

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ modules/pages/content.php?page_url=$1 [NC,L]
```

This is working fine and I can access URL like..

```
http://www.domain.com/example-page
```

Now I want to redirect `http://www.domain.com/example-page` URL to `http://www.domain.com/product/features/example-page`

And my htaccess redirect code is..

```
redirect 301 /example-page http://www.domain.com/product/features/example-page
```

This code is working but I'm getting problem.

When I open URL `http://www.domain.com/example-page` it redirect to `http://www.domain.com/product/features/example-page?page_url=example-page`

But instead of it. I want it to redirect to `http://www.domain.com/product/features/example-page`.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to stick with mod_rewrite and not mix mod_rewrite directives with mod_alias directives (`Redirect 301`). *Before* your rewrite rule routing to `content.php`, add:

```
RewriteRule ^example-page$ http://www.domain.com/product/features/example-page [L,R=301]
```